# Cart Block Does Not Exist After Placing Block in Header, Main Content, Sidebar, or Footer

Tags: commerce, blocks

**Drupal: 10.2.1**
*Commerce Core: 2.37 (Latest)*

I am creating a new store and I have correctly set up my store, products, product types, product variations & variation types. All of the product variations correctly add to the cart after clicking add to cart btn and they are all visible on /cart & /checkout. I  place the cart block in the Header with the settings below. After placing the block the cart icon and the number of items are not visible even after disabling and re-enabling the cart block & cart module, clearing cache, & removing all restrictions in visibility so it will display everywhere. I have ctrl f searched for 'Cart' 'cart' 'cart block' 'item' 'items' with in the web front end and it doesn't exist anywhere. *insanity intensifies*

**Cart Block Configuration**

Title: Cart

Display Title: TRUE

Display cart contents in a dropdown: YES

Response Code: EMPTY

Data comparison:
Data to compare: Interface text
Data value: Interface text

Entity is New:
Product from URL
Negate the Condition: TRUE

Data value is empty:
Data to check: Interface text

Pages: EMPTY (I have tried multiple ways of selecting all of the pages on my site like '/' '/*' 'URL.com/' etc. but still no luck)
Show for the listed Pages: TRUE

Response Status: Success 200, Access Denied 403, Page not found 404 (None show in the Console/Network tabs

Roles: Not Restricted

Webforms: Not Restricted

Product variation type: Not Restricted

Product type: Not Restricted

Content type: Not Restricted

Vocabulary: Not Restricted

Webform: Not Restricted

Region: HEADER

I am beyond clueless as to what is the issue. **Please Help**

Comment: Are you sure you're adding the block to a region in the currently active theme? I don't know what Display cart contents in a dropdown is, maybe it's hidden in a dropdown? For pages choose the opposite, False when showing only on certain pages, that way it shows everywhere.